# to check all 8-neighboring patches with turtles on it? NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I need to check if all the neighboring patches have turtles on them. The code I tried gave the error of  "expected reporter" with set primitive.

My code is

```
  if all? other (people-on neighbors) with [fear?]     [set unable-move? true ]
```

people is the breed, fear is an attribute variable (people-own variable) and unable-move? is a global variable.

At some point I want to stop the person(turtle) if all the 8-patches including the center patch have a person(turtle) on it and are in fear.

Comment: It's easier if you give a short code that can be tested !

Answer (score 4):

The [`all?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#all) primitive requires you to give:

- an agentset for which you want to test a condition (in your case, [`neighbors`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors)).
- a reporter for testing that condition on each agent (in your case, the neighboring patches): `any? people-here with [ fear? ]`.

All together:

```
if all? neighbors [ any? people-here with [ fear? ] ] [
  set unable-move? true
]
```

That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
if (not any? neighbors with [count people-here with [fear?] = 0])
[ set unable-move? true ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to check for all neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

something like :

```
if sum [count people-here with [fear?]] of neighbors >= 8 [
                                      set unable-move? true
                                       ]
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Thank you but actually I meant what sir Nicolas answered.